# How to coerce a list object to type 'double'

Tags: r

The code:

```
a <- structure(list(`X$Days` = c("10", "38", "66", "101", "129", "185", "283", 
                                 "374")), .Names = "X$Days")
```

Then `a` is like

```
$`X$Days`
[1] "10"  "38"  "66"  "101" "129" "185" "283" "374"
```

I would like to coerce `a` to an array of numeric values, but coercing functions return me

```
Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 162, accepted):

If you want to convert all elements of `a` to a single numeric *vector* and `length(a)` is greater than 1 (OK, even if it is of length 1), you could `unlist` the object first and then convert.

```
as.numeric(unlist(a))
# [1]  10  38  66 101 129 185 283 374
```

Bear in mind that there aren't any quality controls here. Also, `X$Days` a mighty odd name.

Comment: the numbers (which are in factor) after running this command change to different numbers

Comment: @PM0087 that’s what happens if “numbers” are stored as factors. Using `as.numeric` in that case will use the underlying integer values to which the factor labels are indexed

Comment: @PM0087 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418128/how-to-convert-a-factor-to-integer-numeric-without-loss-of-information

Comment: Thanks Ben. I've tried both of the top accepted method. `as.numeric(as.character(f))` turns everything to `NA`. `as.numeric(levels(f))[f]` returns error of `invalid subscript type 'list'.`

Comment: @PM0087 you’ll probably have to use `unlist` before converting to numeric or use the `lapply` approach in one of the other answers here, applying one of the factor conversion approaches in the linked q&a

Answer (score 44):

If your list as multiple elements that need to be converted to numeric, you can achieve this with `lapply(a, as.numeric)`.

Comment: the numbers (which are in factor) after running this command change to different numbers

Answer (score 9):

You can also use list subsetting to select the element you want to convert. It would be useful if your list had more than 1 element.

`as.numeric(a[[1]])`

Answer (score 2):

In this case a loop will also do the job (and is usually sufficiently fast).

```
a <- array(0, dim=dim(X))
for (i in 1:ncol(X)) {a[,i] <- X[,i]}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are problems with some data. Consider:

```
as.double(as.character("2.e")) # This results in 2
```

Another solution:

```
get_numbers <- function(X) {
    X[toupper(X) != tolower(X)] <- NA
    return(as.double(as.character(X)))
}
```