# Access transition matrix from markovchainFit object

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe, numeric

I want to first calculate a markov transition matrix and then take exponent of it. To achieve the first goal I use the `markovchainFit` function inside `markovchain` package and it return me a data.frame , rather than a matrix. So I need to convert it to matrix before I take exponent.
My R code snippet is like

```
#################################
#  Estimate Transition Matrix   #
#################################
setwd("G:/Data_backup/GDP_per_Capita")

library("foreign")
library("Hmisc")
mydata <- stata.get("G:/Data_backup/GDP_per_Capita/states.dta")
mydata

library(markovchain)
library(expm)

rgdp_e=mydata[,2:7]
rgdp_o=mydata[,8:13]
createSequenceMatrix(rgdp_e)
rgdp_e_trans<-markovchainFit(data=rgdp_e,,method="bootstrap",nboot=5, name="Bootstrap Mc")
rgdp_e_trans<-as.numeric(unlist(rgdp_e_trans))
rgdp_e_trans<-as.matrix(rgdp_e_trans)
is.matrix(rgdp_e_trans)
rgdp_e_trans %^% 1/5
```

the `rgdp_e_trans` is a data frame, and I try to convert it to a numeric matrix. It seems work when I test it using `is.matrix` command. However, the final line give me an error said

```
Error in rgdp_e_trans %^% 2 : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

After some searching work in stackoverflow, I find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12384071/how-to-coerce-a-list-object-to-type-double) sharing the similar problem and use `rgdp_e_trans<-as.numeric(unlist(rgdp_e_trans))` to coerce the object to be `double', but it seems not work.
Besides, the data.frame rgdp_e_trans contains no factor or characters
The output in the console is like

```
> rgdp_e=mydata[,2:7]
> rgdp_o=mydata[,8:13]
> createSequenceMatrix(rgdp_e)
Error: not compatible with STRSXP
> rgdp_e_trans<-markovchainFit(data=rgdp_e,,method="bootstrap",nboot=5, name="Bootstrap Mc")
> rgdp_e_trans
$estimate
          1          2          3           4          5
1 0.6172840 0.18930041 0.09053498 0.074074074 0.02880658
2 0.1125828 0.59602649 0.28476821 0.006622517 0.00000000
3 0.0000000 0.03846154 0.60256410 0.358974359 0.00000000
4 0.0000000 0.01162791 0.03488372 0.691860465 0.26162791
5 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.044247788 0.95575221


> rgdp_e_trans<-as.numeric(unlist(rgdp_e_trans))
Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
> rgdp_e_trans<-as.matrix(rgdp_e_trans)
> is.matrix(rgdp_e_trans)
[1] TRUE
> rgdp_e_trans %^% 1/5
Error in rgdp_e_trans %^% 1 : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
>
```

Any suggestion to fix the problem, or alternative way to calculate the exponent ? Thank you.

---

Additional：

```
> str(rgdp_e_trans)
List of 1
 $ estimate:Formal class 'markovchain' [package "markovchain"] with 4 slots
  .. ..@ states          : chr [1:5] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  .. ..@ byrow           : logi TRUE
  .. ..@ transitionMatrix: num [1:5, 1:5] 0.617 0.113 0 0 0 ...
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:5] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:5] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  .. ..@ name            : chr "Bootstrap Mc"
```

and I comment out the as.matrix part

```
rgdp_e=mydata[,2:7]
rgdp_o=mydata[,8:13]
createSequenceMatrix(rgdp_e)
rgdp_e_trans<-markovchainFit(data=rgdp_e,,method="bootstrap",nboot=5, name="Bootstrap Mc")
rgdp_e_trans
str(rgdp_e_trans)
# rgdp_e_trans<-as.numeric(unlist(rgdp_e_trans))
# rgdp_e_trans<-as.matrix(rgdp_e_trans)
# is.matrix(rgdp_e_trans)
rgdp_e_trans$estimate %^% 1/5
```

Comment: Try `rgdp_e_trans$estimate %^% 1/5`.

Comment: Seems not work. `> rgdp_e_trans$estimate %^% 1/5
Error in rgdp_e_trans$estimate %^% 1 : not a matrix`

Comment: Could you add the output from `str(rgdp_e_trans)` after you create it with `markovchainFit`?

Comment: Also, did you do `rgdp_e_trans$estimate %^% 1/5` before or after the `as.matrix` transformation?

Comment: @MikkoMarttila Appologize for delayed reply due to time lag. I add additional information according to your suggestion, see the bottom of my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You can access the transition matrix directly from the object returned by `markovchainFit` as:

```
rgdp_e_trans$estimate@transitionMatrix
```

Here `rgdp_e_trans` is your return value from `markovchainFit`, which is actually a list containing the information from the fitting process. You access the `estimates` item of that list by using the `$` operator. The `estimate` object is from a formal S4 class (see e.g. [Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/OO-essentials.html) by Hadley Wickham for a description of the object systems used in R), which is why in order to access its items you have to use the `@` operator instead of the standard `$` used for the more common S3 objects.

If you print out the return value of `as.matrix(rgdp_e_trans)` it should be immediately obvious where your initial approach went wrong. In general it's a good idea to check the structure of an object with the `str` function - instead of relying on its print method - when you encounter unexpected results or are working with new types of objects.

Comment: It works. Also, just in case you need (as I did), You can also access states names through rgdp_e_trans$estimate@states.