# Choosing correct data type for dynrq in quantreg R package

Tags: r, xts, quantreg

I'm trying to run a dynamic linear regression on my data:

```
require(RCurl)
y <- read.csv(text=getURL("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zmilhard/helloworld/master/growth_data_2.csv"))
explore <- y[1:87,2:21]
```

I use three different formulas to try to run the regression:

```
require(zoo)
dlr <- dynrq(explore ~ L(explore,1) + L(explore,12), tau = 99/100)
dlr <- dynrq(explore ~ L(explore,1) + L(explore,20), tau = 99/100)
dlr <- dynrq(explore ~ L(explore,1) + L(explore,20), tau = 99/100, start = c(2,1), end = c(87,20))
```

I keep getting the error:

```
Error in hasTsp(x) : invalid time series parameters specified
```

Explore is currently a list. [The example](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/library/quantreg/html/dynrq.html) uses data of double type. When I convert my data to a double using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12384071/how-to-coerce-a-list-object-to-type-double) I get the same error. Do I need to use a time series variable such as xts? Are my formulas faulty?