# GARCH modeling in R and error message "Error in .extractdata(data) : 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'"

Tags: r, error-handling

I am trying to model the amount of revenues with GARCH using the `rugarch` package. Whenever I try and run the GARCH code, I always get the same error message, with it being

```
"Error in .extractdata(data) : 
  'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'"
```

I will include all of my code below, as well as the various things I have tried to use to get rid of this error message. If I need to include more code/specify more things in the future, I am open to suggestions (relatively still new with R). Any help is appreciated!

```
imtired <- read_excel("C:\\Users\\zacha\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Research for roadmap\\imtired.xlsx")                                                                                                                                         

    New names:
* `` -> ...1
> netrevenues = subset(imtired, select = -c(...1, Price, SalesVolume, GrowthRate ) )
> names(netrevenues)[names(netrevenues)=="NetRevenues"]<-"Revenue"
> head(netrevenues)

# A tibble: 6 x 1
    Revenue
      <dbl>
1 25366503.
2 25073396.
3 22637624.
4 16729842.
5 19797980.
6 18226119.
str(netrevenues)
tibble [638 x 1] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ Revenue: num [1:638] 25366503 25073396 22637624 16729842 19797980 ...

    #build first GARCH model
netrevenues1 <- ugarchspec(variance.model = list(model = "sGARCH", garchOrder = c(1,1)),
         mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(1,1)), distribution.model = "std")
         
netrevenuesGarch1 <- ugarchfit(spec = netrevenues1, data = netrevenues)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the problem lies in passing a tibble instead of numeric values into the ugarch-function.

When I had a similar problem, `as.numeric(unlist(netrevenues))`did the job.

I found this solution and a related discussion here
https://www.programmingr.com/r-error-messages/list-object-cannot-be-coerced-to-type-double/ and here
[How to coerce a list object to type 'double'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12384071/how-to-coerce-a-list-object-to-type-double) .