# exact_extract throws error "Error in .num_expected_args(fun) : 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'"

Tags: r, r-raster

I am trying to use the `exact_extract()` function of the `exactextractr::` package to give me the percent area of a polygon covered by each class of a classified raster.  However, I am getting a cryptic error message "Error in .num_expected_args(fun) : 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'."  The error seems to be saying that all of the coverage fraction values are stored in a list, and the summarization routine is trying to convert it to a double-precision datatype. The only thing I can think of is that perhaps this is a bug in the `exact_extract()` function.  Any guidance would be much appreciated.  Below is my reproducible example to illustrate the issue:

```
##Loading Necessary Packages##
library(exactextractr)
library(sf)
library(spData)
library(raster)
library(tmap)

## Getting the State of Oregon from the us_states and projecting it into Oregon Statewide Lambert (EPSG 2992)  
data("us_states")
OR<-st_transform(us_states[us_states$NAME=="Oregon",], st_crs("EPSG:2992"))

##Making a fake classified raster with the same extent and projection as the state of Oregon
FAKE<-raster(ext=extent(OR), res=1000, crs=crs(OR))
values(FAKE)<-sample(c(1:4), ncell(FAKE),replace=TRUE)

#Map to demonstrate that polygon overlays the raster
tmap_mode("plot")
tm_shape(FAKE)+
  tm_raster()+
tm_shape(OR)+
  tm_polygons(border.col="black", alpha=0)

test<-exact_extract(FAKE, OR, fun=count, summarize_df=TRUE) # This will throw an error
```

Comment: I do not have access to a computer right now, but what I can find on the error you specify is [this post](https://www.programmingr.com/r-error-messages/list-object-cannot-be-coerced-to-type-double/) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12384243/10852113). Maybe you can distill some directions out of it as to how to solve the problem.

Comment: Hi Dion, thanks for your reply.  I think I see where you're going with this: I could try to hack the code for `exact_extract()` and put an `unlist()` routine in there to allow the conversion to double precision.  Unfortunately, that won't work because `exact_extract()` is implemented in a different language (I believe C++, but I'm not 100% sure).

Comment: Great that you have found an answer @Sean McKenzie. You may then accepted it as the answer. BW

Comment: SO makes me wait 2 days before I can accept my own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I am just an idiot.  `exact_extract()` expects the functions to be quoted because they are run internally and not taken from the external functions.  This solved the issue entirely:

```
##Loading Necessary Packages##
library(exactextractr)
library(sf)
library(spData)
library(raster)
library(tmap)

## Getting the State of Oregon from the us_states and projecting it into Oregon Statewide Lambert (EPSG 2992)  
data("us_states")
OR<-st_transform(us_states[us_states$NAME=="Oregon",], st_crs("EPSG:2992"))

##Making a fake classified raster with the same extent and projection as the state of Oregon
FAKE<-raster(ext=extent(OR), res=1000, crs=crs(OR))
values(FAKE)<-sample(c(1:4), ncell(FAKE),replace=TRUE)

#Map to demonstrate that polygon overlays the raster
tmap_mode("plot")
tm_shape(FAKE)+
  tm_raster()+
tm_shape(OR)+
  tm_polygons(border.col="black", alpha=0)

test<-exact_extract(FAKE, OR, fun="count", summarize_df=TRUE)
```